# Getting locale functions to work in glibc

Tags: c, locale, glibc, libc, strcmp

I need to make some modifications to the the C standard library (glibc) in order to get some performance improvements. Specifically, I am going to be writing some specialized versions of some of the locale-dependent functions (which in glibc perform poorly), such as `strcoll`.

I have checked out the glibc source from [here](http://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GlibcGit), into `~/Desktop/glibc`. I then ran the following sequence of commands without error.

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ mkdir bglibc
$ cd bglibc
$ ./../glibc/configure --prefix=~/Desktop/bglibc
$ make
$ make install
```

At this point, I have successfully compiled and installed glibc into `~/Desktop/bglibc`. I then created the following test program (`ct.c`) in the bglibc directory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main ()
{
  char *locale = NULL;
  locale = "en_US.utf8";

  char *result = setlocale(LC_COLLATE, locale);
  if (result == NULL) {
    printf("locale not set\n");
  }   

  printf("strcoll: %d\n", strcoll("some", "string"));

  return 0;
}
```

I then build it with this script:

```
iSYSROOT=~/Desktop/bglibc

gcc -o ct ct.c \
  --sysroot=${SYSROOT} \
  -Wl,-rpath=${SYSROOT}/lib \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker=${SYSROOT}/lib/ld.so.1
```

Which builds it properly. I then run it with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
builddir=`dirname "$0"`
GCONV_PATH="${builddir}/iconvdata" \
exec    "${builddir}"/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path "${builddir}":"${builddir}"/*:"${builddir}"/*/*:"${builddir}"/*/*/* ${1+"$@"}
```

Which is names `testrun.sh`. To run it on the program I previously compiled (`ct`), I run `./testrun.sh ./ct`.

This successfully runs the program, however the program prints out `locale not set`, meaning that it was unable to set the locale to `"en_US.utf8"`. Thus, the locale keeps the default (`"C"`), in which case `strcoll` simply returns the result of `strcmp`. However, I need this call to run the `strcoll` code in order to run tests on its performance, and then tune it to run faster for specific locales.

I know that `"en_US.utf8"` is a valid locale for my system (Ubuntu 12.04 lts), because I see this:

```
$ locale -a | grep US
en_US.utf8
```

I have also tried running this program but setting the locale variable to other strings such as `"en_US.UTF-16`", `""`, `"en_US.UTF-8"`, etc. all with no luck.

I imagine this isn't the first issue I will run into when trying to get locale stuff to work with my modified version of glibc, but its the first.

Any ideas On what I can do to get the locale functions (specifically `setlocale`) to work right?

Comment: have you tried setLocale(LC_ALL, locale)?

Comment: Perhaps this link will help: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html

Comment: @Clocks, yes, I have tried using LC_ALL instead and it didn't work. As far as the link goes, that is mostly just explaining "how locale and setlocale works". I understand how the setlocale function and the system locale works fairly well, the issue at hand is a bit more complex. Thanks though.

Comment: For me it the answer from user2898218 worked. Consider to comment it or to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

My guess: You forgot to "make" some locales. Try:

```
$ make
$ make install
$ make localedata/install-locales
```

see also [GNU libc make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Running-make-install.html)

> After installation you might want to configure the timezone and locale
>   installation …

Comment: `make localedata/install-locales` works !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `strace` to find out where the glibc tries to read the locales from. I suspect that since you set the prefix glibc tries to find them in `~/Desktop/bglibc/share/locale/` or something similar. And certainly UTF-16 will not work with 8 bit string types...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked as some of the system calls using strace, and there are a few locale-related ones that like this: 

open("/home/username/Desktop/bglibc/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory).

 So its looking for the locale files in a place where they don't exist (bglib/lib doesn't even exist). I looked around and it seems like they actually reside in this dir: 

 bglibc/share/i18n/locales.

 Why would it be looking in the wrong location? It seems like it should know the correct place to look.

Comment: That I do not know, anyway, a simple symlink would suffice now to just test if the locales work when pointed to right directory

Comment: I have added a symlink to the correct file, but the issue persists. I don't know if you have any other suggestions, but either way thanks for the help.